# There's seriously no reason why LaTeX markup via MathJax shouldn't be enabled on SO

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mathjax

I know this has been discussed over and over again, and it may be very boring and annoying for people who have been around awhile, but I'm telling you: Unless this need is fulfilled, it will continue to come up again and again and again. I've read the other posts about this matter, and as far as I can see some of the best arguments have been put forward by [Neysor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128228/latex-on-stack-overflow-for-dummies?lq=1).

The counter-arguments I have found on the other pages discussing this matter, along with my replies:

- "If you need serious math, the question/answer does not belong on Stack Overflow anyway."

  Well, this may be true when we are talking about programming in C or Visual Basic. It is not true when we are talking about programming in Matlab, or R, or Octave, or Scilab, or … Questions about these languages very often involve the translation of mathematics into code, or programming problems are related to a misunderstanding of the math. Asking such questions and answering them is *much facilitated* by being able to use mathematical notation. Just a few examples I happened to be involved in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744543/why-isnt-the-inverse-fourier-transform-giving-the-correct-results#comment29340393_19744543),
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754324/improving-a-badly-conditioned-matrix/19716062),
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696212/nested-numerical-integration/19715327), and
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086124/why-kernel-smoothing-function-ksdensity-in-matlab-results-in-values-greater-t/19093582).
  I'm sure there are many more.

  I guess one might argue that questions about Matlab & Co. do not belong on Stack Overflow because it is a different kind of programming. But the fact remains that the majority of [Matlab questions on stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/filters/107022/matlab-questions) are on Stack Overflow, and as long as there is no matlab.stackexchange.com, I'm pretty sure they will continue to pop up here.
- "Enabling this means introducing an extremely heavy dependency."

  This does not correspond to my experience on other sites like math.StackExchange that do use MathJax. More objectively speaking, according to [this detailed explanation](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/when-will-we-get-latex-mathematics-support-i-e-mathjax/244#244) *it is simply wrong*. The impact on pages that do not need math is minimal, and those that need it, well, need it.

  Talking about dependency in the sense of "it breaks if something goes away": Given its success, it is very unlikely that MathJax simply goes away, and it is much more likely that those image sites that people use now as a replacement will cease to exist. Moreover, if MathJax goes away there's still the LaTeX code itself which stays decipherable, while if an image site goes away, there's nothing left at all.
- "The developers have better things to do."

  That may very well be true, but the fact is that enabling MathJax does not involve any new development whatsoever. Apart from the fact that this has been done for other Stack Exchange sites already, so it could just be copied: Enabling math simply amounts to including the following lines of code into the HTML delivered by the SO server:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) },
                        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
                        TeX: {  noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } },
                                messageStyle: "none"
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beta.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>

(Taken from math.stackexchange.com.)
```

- "Enabling math puts an additional burden on the Stack Overflow server."

  Delivering eight additional lines of HTML code hardly does that, considering that even a short Q&A page on Stack Overflow may well have 800 lines of HTML code already. And as you can see from the code shown above, everything else is not loaded from Stack Overflow, but directly from mathjax.org. It's the burden on their servers that is increased, and even that is moderate, considering that the javascript files are not that large, and should be cached by the browser.

  The actual rendering is implemented completely client-side.

So, as far as I can see, there is *no valid reason* not to enable MathJax on Stack Overflow. Tell me if I've missed one.

Comment: Well, on the other hand, I don't see a compelling reason to add LaTeX support on [so]. 99% of questions which would require LaTeX would (in practice) be offtopic on [so], even if you will (and I'm sure you can) come up with some valid questions right now.

Comment: Not a reason to avoid it if it was actually *needed*, but... A few of us just finished going through several hundred questions and retagging / editing / closing / deleting. Really glad I didn't have to wait for an extra rendering step while doing this. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I explicitly answered this counter-argument already in the post, in the first list-item. You work with PHP and javascript, I work with Matlab. I need this, and I see that many others have expressed this need, too. – I wonder whether anyone flagging this actually took the time to read.

Comment: It's still a huge dependency, it's additional files, additional scripts, an additional DNS lookup, and a slower page load time. This hasn't changed any.  We won't enable this without an extremely good reason for doing so.  We don't add 30 million file downloads a day to our users just because "there's no reason not to do it". We care about performance, this hurts performance.

Comment: @Shog9: If you are sorting questions that do not contain math, there is no rendering. If you are sorting questions that do contain math, it makes your job easier.

Comment: @NickCraver: Do you have any concrete arguments against the detailed explanation why it is not a huge dependeny, given in the post. This is simply a myth.

Comment: @Shog9: Btw., there were a number of supporting comments here, why did they suddenly all get deleted? And it wasn't them, it was a moderator that was being disrespectful.

Comment: @A.Donda You might want to hold back on the "myth" and other implementation statements. The devs here generally know what they are doing. But is it really so difficult to just generate your equations using an external service and then include the image?

Comment: Knowing the SO userbase like I do, this would get used even when it wasn't strictly needed, just to make certain formatting tasks slightly easier. Or as a replacement for bananas in comments. Which would then require it to be loaded and rendered on a bunch of pages where it contributed nothing useful. We enable this on sites where questions are *very likely* to make good use of it, not as a "nice to have" for the occasional post.

Comment: @Bart it's definitely much harder to edit them that way

Comment: (And there were no comments here when I saw the post - guessing they weren't particularly constructive)

Comment: Yes we have concrete reasons, the additional DNS lookup and script load even when there's nothing to do is a non-trivial delay to page load time, which we care deeply about.

Comment: I made comments here before, but they must have been purged by Big Brother.  I guess Matlab is just sort of a misfit.  Everyone seems to insist that if a problem requires math, then it doesn't belong on SO.  But if a matlab question is not inherently mathematical, it doesn't belong on math.SE.  Since syntactic questions do not belong on CS.SE, I guess that we users of Matlab are meant to be nomads, since there is no place for us.

Comment: @JanDvorak No doubt. But that's not enough of a reason to include it.

Comment: @nispio There is always Area51

Comment: @Bart there's also [mathematica.se]

Comment: Which is why I suggested Area51 @jan

Comment: I do not claim any specific web development proficiency myself. But I linked to a detailed explanation of someone who does seem to be very knowledable. I called it a myth because in everything I have seen it has never been explained.

Comment: @Bart, I explained why external image services are not a good idea in the post. Neysor, in his post linked in mine, gave more reasons.

Comment: @A.Donda You wanted facts? [tag:matlab] has 24k questions total, that's about .3% of all questions on [so]. Along with [tag:r], [tag:octave] and [tag:scilab] you have about 1% of the total percentage of questions on [so], and that's assuming *every single* question needs mathjax (which is obviously not the case). Now you have two options, bad or worse: Bad: add mathjax to the JS files unconditionally, which will inevitably hurt performance, even if only as an initial wave, or worse, conditionally flag posts that need it, and take database space. For 1%, I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: The additional DNS lookup, script load and actual content scan that the script _has_ to do have not been mentioned addressed at all in the linked explanation. And these impact page load speed.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Can you put a number on that performance hit?

Comment: Whatever we do to a page, multiply it by hundreds of millions of times a month. Any additional resources our clients have to load get loaded **hundreds of millions of times**.  Given your own arguments, they're wasting their time and needlessly delaying page load time 99% of the time.  That sounds like a terrible trade-off to me.

Comment: @A.Donda: Sure, initial file download of about 100k, times 30 million unique visits a day, do the math. **Don't forget this is SO we're talking about, it has a *LOT* of visits**.

Comment: @Oded, the content scan is done in the background. It surely needs CPU, but it does not delay initial page rendering. MathJax is smart that way.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I thought user performance was at stake here, not server load

Comment: @JanDvorak: If server load takes a hit **all** users take a hit too.

Comment: @A.Donda remember that any javascript process running in the "background" blocks the user interface nevertheless

Comment: @MadaraUchiha initial file download of 15k, from a server which is not stackoverflow / stackexchange. "On a page with no mathematics where MathJax is loaded, MathJax requires two files: MathJax.js itself and a configuration file. If taken from the MathJax CDN, the file will be shipped in compressed form, and the actual data transfered for MathJax.js will be about 14.4KB. For comparison, the background image for this site (http://cdn.sstatic.net/betameta/img/bg-noise.png) is 12.3KB…"

Comment: @A.Donda you are right... maybe SE should switch to solid color background to reduce server load

Comment: You know... There's no *background image* on Stack Overflow either... Or on MSO, for that matter. Page loads on beta sites are a drop in the bucket here.

Comment: @Shog9: And that's a *very **very*** big bucket.

Comment: @Shog9: The point is, it is tiny. This page on which we are discussing now has 383k, and this is a small one. And again: **MathJax is not loaded from stackexchange servers.**

Comment: It's not tiny, it's 50% more DNS lookups to start, it's another **blocking** operation for the user viewing the page.  Our server load is irrelevant, it's from our CDN and we're more then capable of handling it.  We're talking about *your* page performance here.

Comment: @NickCraver: Well if its about my performance, why are 30 million visits relevant. And why is it that I don't see any bad performance on math.stackexchange.com? Honestly, guys, are you *sure* you have good reasons? Or are you blocking this request simply because you don't like it? No offence intendend, it just feels that way.

Comment: Ok fine...I'll write up an answer with graphs when I get home since you aren't getting it.  I can only do so much from a phone.

Comment: @NickCraver: Sorry to bother you, but this would actually be appreciated. And after that you can really say that the question has been answered and shouldn't be posed anymore.

Comment: I agree, and I'll write up a detailed answer with concrete numbers tonight.

Comment: @NickCraver I assume you'll singlehandedly reopen this at that point. Maybe you should do it now?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Absolutely, since someone in the community is obviously going to have much better information than Nick has.

Comment: Eh? I've answered my share of MATLAB questions and browsed/voted/edited several others and I'll say that there were very few questions where I've really needed MathJax. In most of those cases, I managed to do with just plain-text math (people can understand `A_i` in math means a subscript) and for the rest (perhaps 3-4 answers), I wrote up the equation in LaTeX and pasted a screenshot.

Comment: You think that people will only use MathJax for math on MATLAB/R/etc. question? Boy, are you wrong! Enabling MathJax also enables it on comments and you'll end up with millions of possibly creepy stalker [crackheads who want to pimp up their comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/62172/software?tab=activity&sort=comments) (each of those pluses, hearts, and colors are due to MathJax).

Comment: @A.Donda answer is below, strictly for the performance question.  It doesn't address the other issues such as what the mobile apps would have to do, etc...that's a whole other can of worms.  It's not exactly on-topic for your question, but there are also other external concerns about MathJax now.

Comment: (cc @NickCraver) Here's another fun fact: [giving SO MathJax would be a breaking change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203999/223030).

Comment: Canonical question: *[LaTeX on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559)*

Comment: Superscripts and subscripts (`<sup>,<sub>`) _are_ [allowed HTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), which is good enough in several cases.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

This answer is to specifically address the "it's not a heavy dependency" argument.  How might one do that?  Well I just turned MathJax on for Stack Overflow for a few moments and ran some tests to confirm what we already know here: it makes the page slower.  How much slower?  See for yourself, here's are direct links to the tests. These are the numbers for the first visit (uncached) views of the homepage:

- [Stack Overflow (no MathJax)](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131102_08_QQQ/): **1.380s**
- [Stack Overflow (with MathJax)](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131103_DV_CS/): **1.675s**
- [Math.StackExchange](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131102_BT_QR2/) (with MathJax including content using it): **2.341s**

That's a significant performance penalty, even when "it's not doing anything".  We're talking about a **21.3%** increase in page load time for a user first hitting the site.  Math.StackExchange is provided as a reference because it has the same HTML structure and content (besides MathJax), and actually has some work for MathJax to do...Stack Overflow has none.  Keep in mind the *exact* same servers run all of these, they're literally the same application pool in IIS.

Also keep in mind the testing scenario actually helps MathJax percentage-wise.  Many of the other domains being hit, namely: `edge.quantserve.com`,  `pixel.quantserve.com`, `www.google-analytics.com` and `ajax.googleapis.com` are *very* likely to be in the DNS cache for a client already - they are used for analytics on many websites.  You're seeing costs for those that, on average, is very unrealistic.  `beta.mathjax.org`? that one's not going to be cached for most Stack Overflow users.  Furthermore, jQuery, Google Analytics and QuantCast scripts are likely to be cached...many of those requests aren't just "not a DNS hit"...they're pure cache hits and have practically no time penalty.

This is the one certainty in programming:  **doing something is more expensive than doing nothing**.  When it comes to Stack Overflow we have to have a very, *very* compelling reason to make it *any* slower.  I'll actually write a blog post soon as time allows on SSL and why it'll be optional (e.g. via HSTS) at first for the same reason.

To put things in an aggregate perspective: The homepage is loaded roughly a million times a day on stackoverflow.com, so on an average of 295ms slower x 1 mil hits = 81.9 hours a day of additional load time and 3 million extra requests.  I won't go into how much harder this hits mobile users where HTTP requests are even more expensive.

---

Here's the time breakdown of page loads:

[image: time breakdown key]

Here's the breakdown of loads, this is Stack Overflow today:

[image: Stack Overflow today]
*(note that long stackauth.com SSL negotiation time...we're working on that)*

This is Stack Overflow with MathJax enabled just a few moments ago:

[image: Stack Overflow with MathJax]

Where's all that time going?  Well there's a blocking operation while it fetches the config you can see here:

[image: MathJax blocking]
*(ouch, that DNS lookup hurts, but the blocking for config hurts more)*

Could we move that config to our CDN, to our site?  Sure, *but it still has to load for the page to continue*.  Either way, it significantly delays the time before the page is usable for the user.

Comment: The documentation suggests [that since version 2.0 MathJax does not need to be loaded synchronously/before DOMContentLoaded](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/dynamic.html), so it should be possible to load it asynchronously and not block rendering of the page. Has this possibility been considered?

Comment: @JeremyBanks it's a tradeoff, that introduces a huge delay in math rendering on the page, so the unformatted code is visible for a significant period of time.  Since (so far) we only deploy this on sites where it's actually needed, it's a very perceivable problem.  If Stack Overflow had any significant use of MathJax (if it didn't, we wouldn't turn it on...), then it would have the same issue.

Comment: @NickCraver, thank you very much for the detailed answer. Actually, I find the "repeat view" numbers even more convincing: 0.827 seconds vs 0.341 seconds. This together with Arjan's answer convinced me that it would be a bad idea to have MathJax on SO.

Comment: Yes! When you're doing something millions of times a day milliseconds matter, a lot. One question though; was this the initial page load? You're spending more time doing DNS lookups on your own servers than you are Google's... the first 50ms are blocking and the careers lookup is noticeable when loading the front page. I also notice you've got the tag pictures on imgur couldn't you save another 40ms or so by moving them to the CDN? (or do I just  not have a clue what I'm talking about :-)).

Comment: @ben many user avatars are on i.stack.imgur.com (most new users with an avatar), so we're eating that lookup either way.

Comment: @NickCraver When a user sets an avatar to an `i.stack.imgur.com` couldn't you just download the link and change the reference? (or do I just not have a clue what I'm talking about)

Comment: @Cruncher to where?  Imgur is geolocated to be near you, serving it from our stuff in New York is definitely a net loss.

Comment: @NickCraver Unrelated to my last comment. Is it possible to have a user setting to turn mathjax on and off? Or would that be another overhead?

Comment: @Cruncher we can't really have that, it means unformatted LaTeX everywhere for those with it disabled...we have it or don't at the site level for that reason.

Comment: @NickCraver Re: Asynchronous loading - I don't know about back in December, but it seems like you are doing it now, no? Not sure when it started but every time I visit something at math.se I see the unformatted LaTeX for a few tenths of a second. Oh and, FWIW, as far as UX goes, it's totally OK.

Comment: The homepage of SO is loaded a million times ... for nothing. Anybody that really read the questions that have been posted the last second or so? Except for Jon of course. *Personally* I don't remember ever visiting the homepage on purpose. Anyway, it would be pretty easy to only load when required.

Comment: Yes as @owlstead said only load it when require. Beside that from a stand point of a user I do not care about performance. That is not my buisness. Well from a standpoint of an advertised user I can understand the issue but I find it sad that we do not have math in SO.

Comment: The follow up is at [MathJax-only code snippets could be simplified into Math Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283127/632951)

Comment: So why hasn't MathJax formatting been excluded from codereview.stackexchange.com - a site about `code` review? Or at least tell us why it makes sense to include MathJax on codereview (was it necessary)? btw, I'm not against its having MathJax, because it's certainly possible for a SO  *"how to implement..."* question to actually require enough math that MathJax formatting is the only way to express the questions and answers clearly.

Comment: What I like about this answer is that it gives concrete realizations of the conditions that would need to be met for this to be alleviated; load times faster than that.

Is there anyway browsers could support some kind of precompiled mathjax so nothing needed to be "transferred" or even "loaded" if a mathjax compiler could be standing at the ready? I believe this might be impossible, but I don't know why it would be. Regardless, thank you for putting bounds on your concerns.

Comment: Anyone investigated [katex](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX)? Comparison with mathjax [here](http://www.intmath.com/cg5/katex-mathjax-comparison.php).

Comment: But once the script is loaded it is cached on the user's device, no?

Comment: Any change in this for the likes of jqMath or KaTeX? Both of which seem to be *much* faster than MathJax.

Comment: I don't agree with this reasoning. We better make users pay little more time yet get more quality answers and discussion. Since many of the questions are math oriented this should be turned on.

Comment: Why can't it be enabled on a per-page basis (for pages which use/require it), instead of on a per-site basis (for every page on a site)?

Comment: @ChrisW Several reasons. For example, we'd have to preload all posts (and earlier in the page) and parse their titles and bodies in the question list pages (this also includes user profiles, etc.) which adds significant overhead, buffering, and allocations for Stack Overflow. And posts don't just appear in pages, they appear in APIs, mobile apps, emails, etc. All of these has to dynamically search and enable MathJax. It's still a ton of work for a very low percentage hit - we still don't see this changing in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Has these numbers changed after mathjax cdn move?

Comment: @NickCraver - What tool did you use to do the page load time analysis?

Comment: I don't agree with the sentiment that a few millisecond is worth not having an essential feature. There are millions of questions that would benefit from being able to render math.

Comment: It's been many years since this is discussed. These libraries are likely to be much faster and more efficient now. There are so many way to implement tex without a performance hit.

Comment: @darksky: "*I don't agree with the sentiment that a few millisecond is worth not having an essential feature.*" I don't agree with the sentiment that this is "an essential feature". If you believe that things have changed and improved to the point where the time difference is genuinely negligible, why don't you do the tests and prove it?

Comment: @NicolBolas  I'd like to add my voice to the chorus that this is indeed an important feature and that it would be well worth a slightly slower page load from the user perspective. It comes up A LOT.

Comment: Even as we approach 2020 I don't personally think a pageload time of 1.6 seconds is a significant (I'd even say it's hardly noticeable) increase over 1.3 seconds. But I also don't care for latex or mathjax to be added to SO as I never use them.

Comment: We need this feature added. I'm tired of adding images or neglecting equations in my answers/posts. By the looks of it, others have suggested good starting points at fixing this issue, but it is certainly necessary to add this feature. Also, this is the most extreme circumstance. Loading MathJax for all pages ... really? Common now. This is not a good answer to justify not adding an applicable feature.

Comment: This hasn't been edited since 2013. Can you please update the numbers?

Comment: "We're talking about a 21.3% increase in page load time for a user first hitting the site" what would be a reasonable number for you? Please don't arbitrarily decide that 21.3% is too much without telling us what an acceptable target would be. If this study were done in 2023 and the increase was only 20%, would you edit your answer and recommend SE to enable MathJax here? The staff (and Makoto) keep pointing to this single post which is far too old and seems very biased. What if the increase were only 1%? Would you still be vehemently opposing the majority here?

Comment: It's an incredibly helpful feature that not only improves aesthetics, but also broadens the scope of & enhances the effectiveness information exchange. It's desired by many users, particularly those who invest much time into writing good answers & questions. In terms of performance, there's JS client-side caching to speed up loads. Plus, mods who have to scan thousands of posts can disable JS from particular domains. NoScript has been around for a really long time... You really don't have to deal with it if you don't want to. The same argument saying people understand A_i also works for $A_i$

Answer (score 63):

While loading MathJax for all pages is clearly not a good idea, there are other options.

There's already support for specifying a language for each code block: [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) .
We can use something similar for MathJax:

```
<!-- language: math -->
$$Beautiful Math$$
```

Or even:

```
<!-- language: math -->$Beautiful Inline Math$
```

The comment should only affect the immediate block following it.

Pros:

- Only applicable to posts - does not affect titles, comments.
- No breaking changes - you only get math where you explicitly ask for it.
- Server knows whether MathJax is needed for a page or not, loading it only when necessary * does not slow down most pages (including homepage).

Cons:

- Incompatible with Ajax (?) - Edited/new posts, pagination.
- A little annoying.

Comment: I never missed math on Stack Overflow, but that's another discussion. If it is needed as many people claim, it looks possible.

Comment: You ask to "merge" MathJax with Google Code Prettify? Don't think such thing is really possible...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nope. Just use the same/similar syntax. That isn't even a code block after the comment. Maybe `<!-- MATH -->` is better.

Comment: Fair enough, let's see what dear Mr. Craver will have to say. :)

Comment: Interesting. But as far as I understand, it would still induce a break on a page where first one poster uses something like in Arjan's answer, and then another one triggers the use of MathJax by such a syntax hint.

Comment: @A.Donda - it should only effect the immediate block after it. I've updated the answer to clarify that. Is that better?

Comment: So, you want the renderer parse the post, load MathJax if it finds the construct, and only then render it?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - Yes, that's the idea. Something simpler can also work, for example `math$$...$$`.

Answer (score 48):

Like Michael already commented, it might also be [a breaking change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203999/markdown-rendering-font-weirdly)? Like for:

> [...] which then stores into a $_SESSION - the problem is most of the settings will be set by javascript, and as javascript is a client side script you can't access PHP $_SESSION variables as its server based. [...]

...suddenly rendering as:

[image: Unexpected MathJax rendering]

So, as for *"The developers have better things to do"*, this might need some option to enable it per-post?

Comment: There is a workaround used on [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) you can read about at [Inline LaTeX doesn't seem to work](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/inline-latex-doesnt-seem-to-work) although because of the load times / lack of use don't think it's worthwhile for SO.

Comment: This is a strong counterargument. Of course one could use the standard LaTeX delimiters \\[ \\] and \\( \\) instead of the dollar signs.

Comment: Or we could just get people to use code formatting, which should have been used in this case anyway.

Comment: That text should have used code formatting. I'm not inclined to care about optimising for it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's tons of things that ought to have code formatting and don't. We can't break large parts of the site just because some people messed up. Code formatting or not, there's still valuable information in these places and we *really* don't need to screw up how it displays.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: Yes we can!

Comment: Breaking a PHP post? Seems like a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Not an issue - it could be enabled only for questions edited after the official date of introduction.

Answer (score 20):

It's not just the pageload that takes a hit. It's the preview that takes a hit, too. I've noticed that typing answers on Physics and Math is slower than on SO and MSO, probably because the preview reruns the mathjax renderer every keystroke.

Yes, this could be improved to behave like prettify where prettyprint is only run once every X seconds. But you usually want an immediate preview for MathJax because TeX is hard.

Also, [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) on Stack Overflow is tiny compared to [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) and [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) and .... a lot more. All of these languages love the dollar symbol and have it denote variables or something similarly common. Of course, code formatting protects these from MathJax, but not everyone uses code formatting.

In contrast, for [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab), you probably don't need TeX in every post. I agree that I'm no part of the tagging community so I may be horribly wrong here, but most of your questions don't seem to be the type that require math.

I guess it could be loaded on a per-tag basis as well. Or use something like [the fiddle listed here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/mathjax-on-meta) that lets one decide to load MathJax dynamically.

Comment: +1. I've never wanted this feature, but if there are sub-communities who do, loading it only when the question has a mathsy tag seems to be the *obviously* best solution.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think slower preview is that much of an issue. Preview takes time anyway.

Comment: SO should definitely ask people from other sites where Math is enable, either to reformat Q/A when they decide to migrate them here or not to migrate them or SO to enable Math on SO; otherwise they got totally messy and unreadable with the formatting after the migration took place.

Answer (score -3):

In a recent response I nearly broke my fingers, emulating math notations in hyper text.

We have emulators here, complete runtime engines for certain scripts, which are not labelled ´concurrent to performance´.

There is no qualified reason for not having an assistant, that generates math notations, without changing basic technical capabilities of the platform and without wasting users's time.

Comment: Re *"nearly broke my fingers"*: That is what macro keyboards are for (or the equivalent). For instance, I have a macro key (without any modifier keys) to enclose the selected text in [`<kbd></kbd>`](https://pmortensen.eu/world/FixedStrings.php).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Yes, and it's a torture compared to Latex-Style notation. That's why would love to have an assistant for composing math expressions, e.g. as Word has a formula editor, where you don't need to care about the unreadable equivalent script.