# MathJax-only code snippets could be simplified into Math Snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, mathjax

The request to enable MathJax on SO was [declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282) for some good reasons. But after that discussion, [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) were introduced, making it possible to load and execute external JavaScript *on demand*. In particular, MathJax can be used to render math formulas in Stack Overflow posts in this way. An example, from a real question asked today, appears below - I copied the text and  wrapped the formula in a snippet.

---

### Numerically solving 2D integral equation in MATLAB?

For example, I would like to solve such a self-consistent equation:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts:["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" });   </script>

$$f(x,y)=\int_0^\infty dp\int_0^\infty dq \frac{pqf(p,q)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
```

... [rest of the post skipped]

---

There are two obvious drawbacks of using code snippets in this way:

1. One has to paste in a line of code to load and configure MathJax, which has nothing to do with the content of the post.
2. The script executes on another domain, with the result inserted in a frame under the post instead of replacing the LaTeX markup as MathJax would normally do.

Both of those could be mitigated by recognizing Math Snippets as a special case of Code Snippets: they would load only MathJax, and (since there are no user-supplied script) run directly on the page. Rough mockup included:

> [image: mockup]

The presence of unrendered LaTeX markup on the page (until/unless the reader clicks the button) is  not really different from the presence of unrendered HTML  markup in code snippets.

Comment: Why code snippets then? Can't MathJax be enabled as it was done on several SE sites? Why do you need excess buttons...

Comment: Because the proposal to load  MathJax on page load was [declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282).

Comment: Ok, convinced me :)

Comment: If Math Snippets would run directly on the page, HTML should be escaped or filtered out.

Comment: What if embedding a special kind of (exceptional) `<!-- language: lang-mathjax -->` language tag would include the MathJax script in a post, but only in that post? I mean, the MathJax script would not be enabled in every post. Would that be even possible (sorry for lame suggestion, I'm not a web developer)?

Comment: This seems like a "hammer to kill a mosquito" solution. If SO posts need math notation, SO should enable LaTeX support, not introduce a system that makes including math notation in a post *more* complicated. If enabling LaTeX support in a way that works for other SE sites doesn't work for SO, we need a better SE-network-wide way of handling LaTeX. If the reasons SO doesn't support LaTeX have something to do with the expected content of posts... maybe math-heavy posts are a better fit for programmers.SE or cs.SE?

Comment: @rickster If you've found a way to avoid the performance hit of enabling MathJax on SO be sure to post it, but if you look at the linked post you'll see that it has a 20% overhead even in the best circumstances at the moment. This seems like a good compromise.

Comment: And what about detecting MathJax markup when the question is posted/edited and setting a boolean field in the post's model, and then use that to only load the MathJax library when the post needs it ? The database is accessed each time the question page is rendered anyway, so I don't think it will cause any issues and will avoid the (little) performance overhead caused by enabling Mathjax on all pages.

Comment: I'm sad that this proposal got lost in the fray for 2 years. It's a good idea because it allows minimally loading mathjax only on those pages that explicitly request it.

Answer (score 11):

Whether SO implements your idea or not, I'm glad to see that it's possible to render MathJax using Stack Snippets! I might have to revise some of my answers.

It would be nice to be able to use LaTex instead of Markdown syntax for things like inline subscripts, superscripts, summations, etc., and this seems like a good way to enable that, without incurring the MathJax download and rendering penalty for posts that don't need it.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a good compromise, but it should take only one click to render all the equations on the page.