# Why is the community so vindictive about theoretical questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm referring to my question here: [Why does the greatest IEEE floating point representable number smaller than 1 differ from 1 by half a machine epsilon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281798/why-does-the-greatest-ieee-floating-point-representable-number-smaller-than-1-di)

I was asking a genuine question and had an issue with the question title phrasing, which I later fixed. Despite this I got multiple downvotes **after** the fixes, clearly indicating the question was not well received since it does not have any code in it. Thing is I initially put a theory tag for that purposed but was edited out anyway, apparently another case that theory tags are not welcomed (why does this tag exist then?).

The question was quite an intersection between THEORY and PRACTICE - IEEE FP is something I thought was used in practice instead and so I asked on SO. Why is the community so hateful against people who post such questions? Is it because I'm low rating? The community is just so unwelcoming here.

Also, my flags for intervention didn't work out either. What could **constructively** be done to improve the situation instead of downvoting the question when one is *genuinely* trying to learn?

Comment: You're seriously asking why a site for programming questions isn't interested in getting non-programming questions?  I would think the answer to that would be self-evident.  And no, it's not because you have a low reputation score.

Comment: @Servey SO is dominated by programming questions - but that doesn't mean it is exclusively for non-programming, and nothing in the site policy enforces that either. There HAVE been questions with zero code and are still well received. But that was a few years back and times have changed? Where else do you suggest I ask the question then? Or do you prefer that I leave the community as a whole and not ask questions anymore?

Comment: The site is *specifically* for programming questions.  Now you can have a programming question that doesn't involve code, sure.  There certainly are questions *about programming* that don't have code in either the question, the answer, or both, but they're still *questions about programming*.  Questions that aren't about programming off topic.

Comment: @Servy see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281237/is-the-use-of-machine-epsilon-appropriate-for-floating-point-equality-tests?rq=1 There is no code. The content is also about IEEE FP. The question has many upvotes. Question was many years ago, perhaps when the community was kinder. Where in the site policy does it say SO is only for programming questions?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the other sites on the network to know if that question would be on topic on any of them, you're welcome to look around at some sites and see if it might be on topic on any of them.  Whether  you want to leave or not is entirely up to you, just be sure to ask *on topic* and otherwise appropriate questions if you stay, rather than asking off topic questions and insulting people when your off topic questions get downvotes.

Comment: @Servy, Are questions about IEEE floating point not on topic? It sure seems like an _answerable question that is unique to software development_...

Comment: @Servy How is my question not on-topic? There are existing tags INCLUDING tags with `theory` that is used over a thousand times. Does that mean all those questions are invalid then? I used the tags as appropriately as I could. You can't say I am off-topic if you can't explain why.

Comment: You're welcome to look through the help center to see what types of questions are on topic for the site.  There's a whole section addressing just that issue.

Comment: @Servy help center says: "if your question generally covers a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" how is asking about IEEE floating point not the case?

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 So are you actually asking the question in the context of software development?  What is the software development problem that you're trying to solve by asking that question?  Make that clear in your question, and then it's a question about software development, rather than a non-programming related question.

Comment: @Servy where else would you find IEEE FP used in any other places except software development? This topic is unique to software development. please don't try to change the premises of the original statement in the help center - there's nothing say it should be in the context of software development, although this is as valid, you shouldn't see it as mutually exclusive. And no, I'm not trying to insult anyone as you mentioned. But the level of passive aggression indicated here is unjustified.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 So are you actually asking that question in the context of a programming problem?  If so, then why say your question isn't a programming question?  *You* are the one asserting your question isn't about programming.  If your question is actually about a programming problem, then *explain that programming problem*, if it's not, then apparently your question isn't about software development.  All that said, yes, floating point numbers are indeed used in contexts outside of programming.  They *can* be programming questions, but they can also not be.

Comment: @Servy I see we have different definitions of non-programming - I see that as a lack of code and so "no programs related" content is in the post, but mostly meant it as a theory based question. It's easy to criticize or give downvotes: but what really other alternatives could be done? What do you suggest could be done better? What could downvoters do except to discourage people?

Comment: You mention flags.  What flags did you use and why?

Comment: Note that 'vindictive' is abusive and unwelcoming.  What did you do, or think you did, that might draw a revenge attack?

Comment: One needs to wonder why a post with such obscure [tags] gets so many votes.  Most popular one was [floating-point], it only has 237 users that favored it.  You must have done something to draw more attention to the post, from users that were not impressed by it.  Careful with those flags, they are a loaded weapon that can easily shoot your left foot clean off.  Same story for inappropriate tags, this is not [theory] by a long shot.

Comment: Well, the good intention is sometimes an unfortunate minority in the possible motivations of the question voters. There is also a site for Computer Science, https://cs.stackexchange.com . You can also check this. In my opinion, your question was unfairly downvoted, also I've experienced this many times.

Comment: To learn on the SE is hard, very hard. It is because you can't ask anything. To create an answerable, on-topic question, and then maintaining it, is often more work as to find the answer for yourself. In my opinion, it worth its price only for the questions, whose answer you simply can't find anywhere. Not, you've got 3 up and 7 downs, it results a rep gain of 1 for you (3*5 - 7*2), despite that the score of your question is negative.

Comment: @Servy I consider it as a signature of degeneration, if such a question is not considered a programming one. Programming is not only the lexical knowledge of the different APIs and language syntaxes.

Comment: @MartinJames From my experience here any question that does not have any code seems to annoy people and leads to downvotes immediately. Why? My only guess is there are people who expect some solvable question to answer when they click on it, and when they see either 1) too short a question or 2) a theory question which necessitate a good understanding of computer science to answer, they felt they've wasted their time clicking on the question and so downvote. Not an unreasonable guess in my opinion. In any case, I feel very unwelcome and have decided to leave.

Comment: When downvoting, the tool tip says to proceed to give a comment if you think the question can be improved. Clearly most people don't care to give any, perhaps due to my low rating indicating I'm not useful to the site anyway. The information asymmetry that people with high rating benefits from also deters others from down voting them. Having a low rating doesn't protect you this way, which is grossly unfair.

Comment: The `theory` tag clearly says there are some questions which can be programming-agnostic and "questions that focus on theoretical aspects rather than practical implementations" Am I missing something here when my question exactly fits into this criteria? So why am I not allowed to use this tag if 1.5k+ questions have used it? Why is my question not welcomed by so many? I cannot find an answer except for the fact that people in this community do not like such questions.

Comment: I don't for a fact doubt that people are not rational all the time, and a cursory downvote without thinking is not far from imagination. It's poor culture in my opinion.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 User don't always comment when voting. This can be annoying when one wants to know the reason for the vote, but there are good reasons to not always comment when downvoting. See [Why isn't commenting mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1288408)

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 About the more broad view: the SE is a profit-oriented company, they have to fulfill what the market wants. Their money depends on, how many programmers can they attract here. If the majority of these programmers is incapable to understand, what is a floating point format, it is not the mistake of the company. They have to build a system which attracts so many programmers as possible. [I think, this may be the reason, why were already so many alternative sites constructed.](https://stackexchange.com/sites) They won't lose also you.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 Yet another side note: checking your main site posts, I have the impression that you are weak in formulating the questions titles. But the titles are very important - answerers see 50 of them in a column, and it is up them, where do they click. My advice is to take *much more effort* to formulate your titles, they are so important as the body of the question! A good question title is short, but it contains the essence of your question. I think your titles are too general. The title should be specific.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 Most of your questions would be ontopic on the https://cs.stackexchange.com , and they are much more welcoming as the SO. Give them a try.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 I think, you have mainly right. However, the SE is more than the SO, it is a complex site network. If your question is closed here as off-topic, you are free to ask it elsewhere. Furthermore, collecting 3000 reputation, you can issue reopen and "leave open" votes in the cases similar like you. The site requires reviewers who didn't forget that programming is more than the lexical knowledge of the APIs.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 I think the reason of the downs were this time, that most of the programmers today simply didn't ever learn that the bit-level exists and how the things are going there. Your question looks so uncommon for them, that they doesn't even see that it is a programming one. The voters wanted questions about lexical things and this is why they seem disliking your question.

Answer (score 17):

#### To answer specifically your title question<sup>1</sup>

> Why is the community so vindictive about non-programming questions?

Because we are a site for questions and answers *about programming problems.*

Let me quote the [tour<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for you:

> **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run *by you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.
> <sub>(emphasis original)</sub>

Now, the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page of the [Help Center:](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
> who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
> questions have a bit of **source code** in them, but if your question
> generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software    development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
> <sub>(emphasis original)</sub>

So... Non-programming questions are definitely a no-go.

#### Regarding your *specific* Stack Overflow question

Just because a question doesn't have code *does not* mean it's a "non-programming question" by any means. Code is not a requirement to ask questions here, depending on what you're asking, and we don't *only* accept debugging questions.

As far as I can tell, your question is a programming related question, it's just not a *debugging* question. ***However,*** being generally unknowledgable about your question, I can't say how well it meets our standards or guarantee that it *is* on-topic, so I can't say why you were downvoted. Really, only the downvoters can explain that. I've been wrong before about on-topicness of questions, so do take my thoughts on this matter with a grain of salt.

#### Regarding tags

Please keep in mind, just because we have a tag on the site doesn't mean that everything applicable to that tag is on-topic here. For example, just because we have the tag [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) doesn't mean we'll help you troubleshoot a non-programming related issue you have, such as figuring out how to non-programmatically change a setting in Windows. Like wise, the tags [theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/theory) and [practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/practice) don't necessarily mean every question that could possibly fit under those tags is on-topic here.

#### Regarding Flags

> Also, my flags for intervention didn't work out either.

There really isn't anything on your question that you could've flagged for. It wasn't closed or deleted, so that means the mods can't do anything for you. They can't say *"Hey, no, bad users, don't downvote this!"* because that's just not how the site works. The mods can't see *who* downvoted your question, and they can't revert the downvotes on your question.

So, with this in mind, there really wasn't anything *for* your flags to work on.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Based on the original title of the question.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> By the way, you should give that a read when you've got a chance. It really explains a lot about our mission and goals, *and* you get a badge for it.</sub>

Comment: To better answer your reply, I meant non-programming as in theory based questions without any code. By any measure I consider IEEE floating points to be something widely used and considered in practice, which is why I posted it on SO which has a greater practice orientation. Who is to decide what is on-topic? I used the tag in honest hopes that it is the right category and note that I don't see why my question still doesn't fit into theory. The lack of that tag seems to invite more hate towards my question.

Comment: If code is not a requirement to ask a question here, then I'm sure my question is on-topic. Tell me why is it not. compared to other sites, SO is more popular for IEEE floating point problems (with obvious reasons). that is why I posted my comments there.

Comment: Can you tell me why my question is not a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"? Where else would you see such floating point considerations apart from software development? I feel that people do need to read more about the help center guide and think before they downvote so cursorily. In my case, I got a really good answer from an experienced user, which has helped me. If my question was that bad, how could this person answered it so clearly? Food for thought.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 On your second comment: Kendra's answer appears to lean towards considering your question on-topic (as I do, FWIW).

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 As duplode said, I really do lean towards the question being on-topic. I can't give it a 100% "this is totally definitely on topic", but it looks on-topic to me. As for the "theory" part of things, I noticed you re-worded it. I really don't have a great way at the moment to re-word that part of my answer, so there's just a note there for now.

Answer (score 10):

> Why is the community so hateful against people who post such questions? Is it because I'm low rating? The community is just so unwelcoming here.

Please [do not interpret downvotes as personal attacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366889/can-we-make-it-more-obvious-to-new-users-that-downvotes-on-the-main-site-are-not).  And I'm pretty sure that calling a community "hateful" is a good way of inviting more ire.  As others have already suggested, many of the downvotes are likely due to the lackluster formatting.  I personally found your question very hard to read, and that certainly fits the bill for downvoting.

> What could constructively be done to improve the situation instead of downvoting the question when one is genuinely trying to learn?

Edit your question to be more clear and better formatted.  You could also try to point out what you understand about that IEEE standard and then point how you arrived at the conclusion you're asking about.

As an aside, theory questions about IEEE floating point numbers seem [on-topic on Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as a "model of computation."  Your question might even already be answered there.

Comment: What do you think can be improved in the formatting? That is the best way to represent floating points for me. SO does NOT have any latex functions, which I would have used. Can you give something more concrete? Why can't people comment on ways to improve instead of just giving a down votes? From my time here I have almost always a downvote leads to even more downvotes.

Comment: Can you go to my question and personally do an edit in a way that you find it fit for consumption? Can you do it in a clearer way?

Comment: I have to agree with @oldselflearner1959 here. There is no truly satisfactory solution for formatting math in SO. One might be willing to to approximate LaTeX/MathJax through [a hand-picked combination of HTML and Unicode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285924/2751851). The absence of that, however, does *not* justify a downvote.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly your question is a processor architecture one and not a programming question, it's mostly mathematics and electronics and is not really related to programming, where your second example [Is the use of machine epsilon appropriate for floating-point equality tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281237/is-the-use-of-machine-epsilon-appropriate-for-floating-point-equality-tests?rq=1) has a real programming goal.

Moreover your question is not really clear, it looks like typed in a hurry and messing with formatting:

> Then the difference or ulp for 1.0 - k = 2^0 x 0.00000.....1.
>
> isn't that the same as machine epsilon, where we have N epsilon = 2^0
>   x 1.000000....1 - 2^0 x 1.000 = 2^0 x 0.000.....1?

And lastly you don't look like asking a programming question but rather multiple processor mathematics questions:

> Why is the correct value half?
>
> Also, how would one calculate ulp for values other than 1.0?

I think (not acted on this question before seeing it here) downvoters found it hard to read, not really clear and as the downvote tooltip say: 'Not useful'.

> Why is the community so vindictive about non-programming questions?

So that's not much about being non-programming, we may have an idea of someone writing yet another operating system for a class or whatever purpose and derive the use from the question, the main problem I see is the impression it gives while reading of hasty write and unlikely to bring things more useful than what the IEEE standard already states.

Comment: "Mostly your question is a processor architecture one and not a programming question, it's mostly mathematics and electronics and is not really related to programming" -- Do we actually *want* to rule out questions about a standard for something (floating-point numbers) which is essentially about computation (and in a very concrete manner at that), and that is implemented by lots and lots of libraries and languages?

Comment: @duplode not when there's a programming goal behind, when it is pure theory and loosely related (let the answerer guess the goal behind) then extra care has to be put in the question, my point here is the down votes comes probably more from how the question is written than the question itself.

Comment: @duplode I didn't check again but the meta question is about the down votes, the question was not closed for off topic and I don't argue for it to be closed here

Comment: [1/2] The Meta question is partly about whether it is a problem to ask what the OP refers to as "theory" questions. That being so, even though it doesn't mention closing (for all we know, the OP might not even have been aware of our closing mechanics), it suggests the issue of whether the main site question is on-topic. In turn, your first paragraph, as I read it, casts a fair amount of doubt on it being on-topic ("Mostly your question [...] is not really related to programming").

Comment: [2/2] On the downvotes: there is a subtle, but important, difference between speculating why downvotes were cast and justifying the downvotes (or telling the OP to adjust they behaviour to the rationale of the downvoters, which in the end boils down to the same thing). In this case, I think the reasons you mention might explain them, but I don't think they are good reasons, and I wouldn't have downvoted for them (i.e. neither for asking at once two tiny, very closely related questions stemming from a common root, nor for not using math formatting given there is no proper way of applying it).

Comment: @duplode the formatting problem was not math formatting but the same sentence split on two paragraphs. My first sentence means the question is border line with math.se or computer engineering.se and was to clear up the problem is not the subject of floating point numbers. See the first revision of the question maybe as the title change has partly made my answer off. All in all I just pointed out what was things usually found 'bad' in question, the main cause still being 'not usefull' IMO

Comment: @Tensibai You gave 3 reasons to rationalize the downvotes. 1) not programming related - I strongly disagree since this is a fundamental in programming and I had further tagged it with theory. 2) poor formatting, which you strongly reiterated in your conclusion in the post - again I disagree. Could you suggest some formatting that is clearer than what has been done to make the question clearer? If so, please go to the question and make the edit to prove this. It's easy to criticize and not come up with any solutions. 3) Where else would you post this question on ''processor arithmetic"?

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 I may have said more explicitly what I meant, but you have enough answers around now. 1) this is not theory, this is a limitation of binary encoding. 2) see the second block quote, it's hard to tell if this is really two sentences or one badly SPLIT. But I won't go edit a question I don't find useful and I can't guess your reasons to ask it. 3) You're showing more effort in whinning than reading as I already named two site and what I find like bad faith makes me reluctant to give you any link to the sites as I'm not convinced you'll read their tour before asking.

Comment: @Tensibai [1/3] (1) "the same sentence split on two paragraphs" -- I hadn't thought of that when reading your post because, as I understand it, paragraph breaks are more a matter of copy editing than of "formatting". That is still no good reason for a downvote, though. (2) On other sites: (a) It is questionable whether Math.SE would be a more appropriate place. See [this question on their Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19627/380202). (b) There is no "computer engineering" site. SE.SE wouldn't be a good fit, as this question is not about design and, so to say, too concrete --

Comment: @Tensibai [2/3] cf. the kind of questions under [their \[floating-point\] tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point). [The Electrical Engineering site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) could be a good fit, though I insist on that not making the question off-topic here ([The scopes of SE sites aren't disjoint](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5563)).

Comment: @Tensibai [3/3] (3) "You're showing more effort in whinning than reading [...] what I find like bad faith" -- This is unnecessarily aggressive. Furthermore, it doesn't work all that well as a riposte, given that one of your suggestions is questionable, and the other is a site that doesn't exist.

Comment: @duplode indeed, I was thinking about https://scicomp.stackexchange.com (without any guarantee it would be on topic there, and I won't spend more time on this) but anyway I just state how I feel about why I won't go further, that's not agressive it's just a reason. Stop looping about on/off topic I already stated I don't find it off topic, just not useful in any manner without a goal behind.