# Is there a way to detect math formatting in Stack Overflow posts, a la Math Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, markdown-rendering, formatting, mathjax

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492342/the-differences-between-the-return-times-to-a-recurrent-state-of-a-discrete-mark) on Math Overflow for reference. It has several math equations that are "detected" by either surrounding the equations in dollar signs ($) or starting newlines and beginning with a backslash (\).

Trying $AA + AB = AC$ doesn't work here, unfortunately.

Is there any way to add that kind of mathematical detection to Stack Overflow posts? If not, can it be added?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33282786/2756409) brought the missing feature to my attention.

Comment: MathJAX-integration would have quite a cost, and to date it's for that reason getting rejected.

Comment: Also relevant: [MathJax-only code snippets could be simplified into Math Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283127/mathjax-only-code-snippets-could-be-simplified-into-math-snippets)

Comment: @Deduplicator Ah, thanks, I didn't know it was called MathJax; that would've helped my search.

Comment: For future reference, you can always type your equation into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to get an image that you can embed, if you don't have a standalone tex tool. (Something like this: [\Gamma = \theta + sin(\theta^2)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\Gamma+%3D+\theta+%2B+sin%28\theta^2%29))

Comment: @theB Thanks! Though the request was specifically asked with the thought in mind to get rendered equations as text so that they can be copied/pasted. :-)

Comment: I know. I also know that it's never going to be added to the site, hence the workaround. One other workaround is to use HTML entities like `&Delta;` which renders correctly in an actual post, if not in comments.