# How to format mathematical expressions?

Tags: support

On [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) it is possible to format mathematical expressions as in TeX.

[Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675522/60764): $A^{2} + B^{2} = C^{2}$

How do I enable the math rendering on Stack Overflow?

Comment: MathJax is not enabled on SO because the library is somewhat expensive (both for clients to load the  library and for the library start-up time). At the levels of traffic SO sees, it is just not worth it for what is really a niche use here. So no, there is no math rendering support on SO.

Comment: See also [*Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)

Comment: Notice the workaround that is available by using a Stack Snippet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283127/mathjax-only-code-snippets-could-be-simplified-into-math-snippets

Comment: The questions you have referenced do not answer the question. They discuss pros and cons of MathJax. What is the answer to my question? Imgur?

Comment: @ceving or rene comment just abvoe yours : use a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @Walfrat For me that is just a silly no-go. Should I create for every single formula a Snippet, which has to be executed by the user in order to see the expression? I have no idea, why people suggest that. And I have absolutely no idea, why people point out that others have suggested that.

Comment: No problem but since you didn't reacted to rene's workaround..., so an Image I guess.