# Is it necessary to include LaTeX?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Some questions are enriched if mathematical foundations are added either to express Boolean logic, formal languages, metrics and other aspects. While for these issues is the site of "computer science", perhaps the question is correct on this site, but some form of expressing mathematical also needed. Should this happen, it would be a good idea to add support for formatting mathematical expressions, as LaTeX; in this way the user can ask her questions with a good foundation and another person can read comfortably to respond better.

So my question is, would be right to add new functionality to the site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> would be right to add new functionality to the site?

No, it wouldn't be right to add MathJax (LaTex/Tex) support to Stack Overflow.

The number of posts that would benefit from TeX support is minuscule, compared to the those who won't. Most posts that would benefit from it still manage to be perfectly clear without.

Now, given that this is both an additional resource to download and that there is a client side rendering step (where the contents of the posts is parsed, TeX sections re-rendered and the result displayed back), the user experience suffers.

This is not a penalty worth making for a large percentage of users that will not benefit from Tex support in any form or way.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/1583) by Nick Craver for numbers and details.

Comment: Has SE looked at server-side rendering of MathJax? That would eliminate the cost for all pages without any Math on it. The output formats are still limited from what I understand (SVG, MathML and the new CommonHTML), but it might already be good enough for the sites that don't need the whole MathJax feature set.

Comment: @MadScientist Or the server scans though the contents, and only directs the client to load MathJax if some Tex has been detected. Then normal posts don't suffer, and mathy posts are happy. And you don't need server side rendering, so the impact for the servers in minimal too.

Comment: @MadScientist - we did look at options for server side rendering, none of which were good. We are also loath to add a JavaScript rendering step to our post rendering pipeline.

Comment: @matsjoyce - not as simple to do at scale. Scanning each and every post on load requires some CPU. Scanning on batch would require storing a flag against each post (or rather set of question and its answers) indicating it contains MathJax. This isn't a small amount of data to store and keep in sync (given that posts can be edited). Again - for the small benefit it might have for some posts - the cost is too high.

Comment: The scanning could be done on the client side when submitting the answer / question / edit (or while writing e.g. if Tex button pressed), and it would only need about 1 byte more of storage?

Comment: @matsjoyce - 1 byte of storage? For how many millions of posts (across 130 sites)? And sure, we _could_ do this on post/edit.