# How can I write math equations in tag wikis?

Tags: feature-request, edits, tag-wiki

I have this equation in LaTeX format:

```
height = \frac{H \ast  D}{\sqrt{W^{2}+H^{2}}}
```

It is converted to image (using a external compiler):

[image]

Can I use latex (or other) to write math equations in tag wikis, so that it will be converted to images automatically? Or must I use images?

Comment: Is really necessary to have it in a tag wiki?

Comment: @Braiam It depends, for me it's very important, others suddenly, it isn't important

Comment: Only on sites that have LaTeX support enabled, which Stack Overflow does not. You'd have to make a very compelling argument for it to be enabled here.

Comment: Relevant to title, in some simple cases, if not to your specific equation: Superscripts and subscripts (`<sup>,<sub>`) are [allowed HTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a select handful of sites in the network (LaTeX.SE, Math.SE, Physics.SE, and others I'm likely leaving out here) have TeX support enabled.  It's a [very heavy performance hit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/1079354) on Stack Overflow - likely due to the site's size *alone* - and as such, wouldn't be a wise thing to add in the few cases that it's had to be used.

I've only ever run into the desire to use LaTeX in questions or answers about five times in the last 3+ years.  I feel that for the sake of *overall* site performance, me having to use a picture to express TeX is a fair compromise.

Comment: [List of sites with MathJax support.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) Also, [TeX.SE does not have MathJax enabled.](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/181)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of "LaTeX" instead of MathJax, but you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Since TeX support is enabled on a limited number of stackoverflow sites, the second best option is to use an [online TeX compiler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online) (if you don't have one installed):

1. Convert TeX code to an image
2. Add image to the tag wiki page.
3. Add source code to the image's alternative text.

`![height = \frac{H \ast  D}{\sqrt{W^{2}+H^{2}}}][1]`
`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvD5I.gif`

[image: height = \frac{H \ast D}{\sqrt{W^{2}+H^{2}}}]

Why do I think it's good to include source code? It allows further editors to fix mistakes or add other TeX images based on the previous ones.

Comment: Better, use it as (part of) the alt-text.

Comment: @Deduplicator is alt-text ever shown?

Comment: Yes, if you hover over an image. Or don't show images.

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree that this is a better option. Updated my answer.