# LaTeX on Stack Overflow: any way to include a formula?

Tags: discussion, support, formatting

Is any painless solution out there to include LaTeX formulas in a Stack Overflow post?

Of course I could render the every formula manually, make a picture (lets say a jpeg) out of it, upload it to some image hoster and then post the image but this is far too much of a hassle..

For example writing about filtering or clustering algorithms, complexity stuff, neural networks, is really a pain without LaTeX formulas.

This is **not** a duplicate of ["*There's seriously no reason why LaTeX markup via MathJax shouldn't be enabled on SO*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on). I am not asking to include LaTeX on Stack Overflow. I am asking if anyone knows a more or less painless alternative to manually render a LaTeX formula and upload it to some image hoster and then include the image.

Comment: Closely related: [There's seriously no reason why LaTeX markup via MathJax shouldn't be enabled on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on)

Comment: @theB:  It's definitely *not* a dupe, but it's related.  It's not a dupe since it's not asking the same thing ("Why can't we use LaTeX on Stack Overflow" vs. "How do I embed a LaTeX formula on Stack Overflow?").

Comment: Why should this be a duplicate? I am not asking for includig MathJax to SO or enable direct LaTeX support in SO. I am asking if anyone knows a more or less painless alternative to manually rendering and including the image of a formula then.

Comment: Note that you do not have to upload any image to a separate image host. Stack Overflow has an "insert picture" button in the editor which allows you to upload images. They are then hosted under a Stack Overflow Imgur account.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the *very* niche scenarios I've had to write TeX, I've found the [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) to be a nice compromise.  You still have to embed the image on the site, which isn't as cool as just rendering MathJax or TeX, but it'll get the job done in a pinch.

In scenarios in which you *do* find yourself writing copious amounts of TeX, you should also consider if the question is more math-oriented than programming oriented, and would thus be on-topic for [Mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Of course math-oriented stuff should be posted on mathematics.se, but I think most guys on meta.so forget about Data Mining, Artificial Intelligence, Big Data stuff, specific algorithms and their complexity, Graph processing, ... Basically nearly all science-related programming tasks highly include math but would not fit on mathematics.se because mainly it is a computer science question. Computer science is highly math related but an own discipline at there are many questions on SO that are primarily about computer science. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Oh.  Well if it's *really* geared towards Comp-Sci, [there's a site for that, too.](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ascenator  More likely than [math.se], a math-heavy programming-related question may be more suitable for  [scicomp.se] or [cs.se] or [dsp.se], or [stats.se] or [datascience.se] -- all of which have MathJax enabled.

Comment: Yeah...I think this is very ambiguous. Basically one has to decide whether the question is more about "practical" programming / implementation or more science related. I would think that most times the realization is more of a problem and therefore more questions on SO appear.

Comment: Also in the computer graphics related tags I can see big potential for equations. It is often hard to explain to a user why his code isn't working without explaining the math behind it.

Comment: -1 for "very niche scenarios". Just had to use a bunch of equations to make a combinatorial point to a newbie asking a programming question.

Comment: @einpoklum:  And how many times have you done that over the last **six years**?

Comment: @Makoto: I've often wanted to include formulas, and have resorted to backticked latex-like code, or some <sub>'s and <sup>'s. This happens to me, on average, I guess once every 6 to 10 answers or so. This time was an exception in that I was replying to a question which itself wasn't stated very clearly, so I wanted more rigor.

Comment: @einpoklum:  Are you *sure* the questions you're answering are even on topic for the site?  [Your most recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733605/1079354) starts with the line "this is not a programming problem" which implies that the problem is more rooted in math than programming, and would be suitable for a math-oriented network site.  It also doesn't help matters much that the question you answered reads like an overly broad requirements dump, either...

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) and embed the result as an image (`![](URL)`). The syntax for using the API is as follows:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=<url-encoded-content-here>
```

The Tex content needs to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which can be done online at for example https://www.urlencoder.org/.

This is an example of an equation rendered by using the Chart API:

[image: Example]

Comment: googleapis isn't available for China users like me, so the images aren't showing for everybody. But I guess we can feed the url to the Stack Imgur upload API.