# How to draw a simple tree in the Stack Overflow editor?

Tags: support, editor

Is there a way to draw a tree (as shown below) in Stack Overflow using any LaTeX package or anything else?

Tree:

```
 1 
 \
  \
  3
 / \
/   \
2    5
   /   \
  /     \
  4      7
       /   \
      /     \
      6     11
           / \
          /   \
          9   12
         / \ 
         8 10
```

Comment: Plenty of tools out there you can use, like http://asciiflow.com/

Comment: @Will asciiflow doesn't actually do that kind of tree.

Comment: Tree (and table!) visualization is something that should probably be supported directly without resorting to manual ASCII drawings or third party sites.

Comment: http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=plants/trees

Answer (score 26):

Edit:

The faster way I found to draw graphs on linux is to use `tree` command:

```
mkdir test && cd test
mkdir -p 1/3/2 1/3/5/4 1/3/5/7/6 1/3/5/7/11
tree && cd .. && rm -rf test
.
└── 1
    └── 3
        ├── 2
        └── 5
            ├── 4
            └── 7
                ├── 11
                └── 6
```

You can use Unicode [box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character):

```
1─3┬2
   └5┬4
     └7┬6
       └11┬9┬8
          │ └10
          └12
```

or alternatively:

```
 1
 │
 3
┌┴┐
2 5
 ┌┴┐
 4 7
  ┌┴┐
  6 11
   ┌┴┐
   9 12
  ┌┴┐
  8 10
```

Or you can draw a tree with graphviz, ie:

```
echo "graph{size=\"2\"; 1--3; 3--2; 3--5; 5--4; 5--7; 1,2,3,4,5,7[shape=plaintext]}" | dot -Tpng > tree.png
```

then put the picture on SO:

[image: tree]

Comment: For the crazy people running Windows, there is also a `tree` command that does the same thing.

Answer (score 16):

TeX is not supported on Stack Overflow (though it is on several other Stack Exchange sites with MathJax).

Instead of using the syntax you have, you can use the html `<pre>` element - white space inside the tag will not collapse.

Alternatively - upload an image.

Comment: OH, that's why my mathjax wasn't working there...  bummer.

Comment: Can we get it for SO too? Please mom.

Comment: @GillBates: iirc, that has been requested before, and rejected.

Comment: @Cerbrus ya: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282/958689

Comment: But even in sites with MathJax, that's only for simple math, isn't it? There is no TikZ.

Answer (score 7):

SO's "insert image" accepts images from the clipboard. So another thing you can do is:

1. Open your favorite image editor (like mspaint on Windows).
2. Draw a tree.
3. Select + copy image.
4. Click the add image button and just paste it right in that window.

[image]

It's very convenient and you don't have to save files, browse for files, or visit other sites. It's also a heck of a lot faster than drawing it with characters.

Answer (score 1):

- Make a directory hierarchy in a temporary folder
- Use the tree command
- Copy and paste the text

Thusly

```
rep /tmp $ mkdir -p a/b/c
rep /tmp $ mkdir -p a/b/d
rep /tmp $ mkdir -p a/e/
rep /tmp $ tree a
a
|-- b
|   |-- c
|   `-- d
`-- e
```