# Why is MathJax enabled on Code Review but not here?

Tags: discussion

I do realize that there's already been [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on) about whether we need MathJax or not. (In fact, there have been several questions related to that). My question's somewhat more specific: I recently noticed that MathJax is already enabled on Code Review; that being the case, why is it be enabled there and not here?

Comment: Did you read Nick Craver's answer about the performance hit on that question? Stack Overflow sees a lot more daily visitors than Code Review does (9.9m vs 57k).

Comment: Code review is a much smaller community.  The hit is not so bad when only a few user (compared to SO user base size) use it.

Comment: @animuson I did see his answer - is the traffic difference actually the main reason at this point?

Comment: I really can't see much else to add to this discussion besides the main points covered in the other question.  Performance is a massive cornerstone of Stack Overflow; if it were to falter for a feature that isn't used on the vast majority of its questions, then there'd be no point.