# Please revisit MathJax on SO

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mathjax

The inability to write mathematical notation as markup leads to some pretty poor workarounds, one of which just came back to bite me in the ass today.

Someone left a helpful comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743742/1726343) indicating I had a typo in one of the formulas. Sweet, no problem, I'll just edit it! Except there's nothing to edit: the formulas are embedded PNGs I created from some LaTeX rendering site a few years ago. The only way I can edit it is to recreate the whole formula (hopefully without any new typos) and render it to a new image.

---

I see [Nick's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/1726343) about the performance penalty from loading the MathJax client side stuff, but I don't understand why you can't just pay that performance penalty on pages that actually contain any MathJax, which is a very small fraction and well worth the trade-off.

I know Stack Overflow already caches its pages, so why can't you just have a fast-to-query bit associated with each cached page that indicates "this page has MathJax in it", and only load the MathJax client stuff on those pages?

Surely there is something that can be done?

Comment: You could always use something free like GIMP to edit the image but that doesn't really help anyone who can't view the images in the first place.

Comment: This is not an especially good motivating example, considering that question really straddles the border between what is and is not on-topic for Stack Overflow (and, in my personal opinion, falls more into the "off-topic" side). There is no practical programming problem there.

Comment: Yes, please. Maybe with client-side lazy loading, despite that leaving unrendered bits on the page longer. The missing MathJax is eternally painful

Comment: *The only way I can edit it is to recreate the whole formula (hopefully without any new typos)* you could have stored the source formula in your answer by surrounding it with html comments`<!-- awesome latex here -->` I think?

Answer (score 14):

In my previous answer I focused on performance and how that negatively impacts users. The counter that keeps coming up it "why not just use it where you need it?". Okay, let's take a look, where is that?

- Questions that use it
- Lists of questions that involve questions that use it
- Related or linked questions that involve questions that have titles that use it
- Links in questions (remember, we put the titles inline) to questions that use it
- Searches that have question or answer results that use it
- ...and probably some more I'm forgetting

Questions that use it: **How do we know?**

Do we do a search on every title and body? To achieve proper performance we have to do this *before rendering the header*, or else the `<script>` include is at the bottom of the page (even worse performance that my answer before assumed possible). This means a lot of scanning and buffering in-memory before we output stream to the client (which happens pretty fast today and will be far faster in ASP.NET Core).

What about all the other question lists that are a link away? Now we need to track a "HasMathJAX" boolean on all questions. This must be analyzed/reanalyzed on render or proactively stored and updated in the database. Now we're talking schema changes for efficiency, but still behind the analysis cost to determine the bit. Note: this won't help users of our API, those users just have to assume *anything* may have MathJAX.

The actual impact isn't actually "just the questions that use it". In a list, linked list, related list, search results, etc. if **1 of 50 questions** use it, that's enough to have to load it. But we have to analyze it server-side to even get it that low.

In any of the above situations, users are loading a lot more JavaScript, have more pages with loading flashes, and have lower performance. The only way for us to counter *some* of this (getting the initial `<script>` to load `async` up top) is to do a lot more work on the server. And I have to stress the "some", because even that does little to counter the user impact.

So the question with any feature/change request remains: is it worth it? I still firmly believe that's a no. It's not worth the performance, perceived performance, or server efficiency tradeoffs involved.

Comment: `and probably some more I'm forgetting` the preview screen when authoring any question or answer that *might* have it (i.e. all of them)

Comment: You set it at the point where the post is being created/edited, you don't search for it every time. Admittedly I don't understand why pages that link to MathJAX answers need it; I wasn't aware MathJAX could even be used in titles (how does this interact with search)? If you only enable it for question/answer bodies, doesn't this eliminate the concerns you've brought up?

Comment: For sites that aren't primarily about mathematics, it would be entirely sufficient to only allow MathJax inside the question body. Titles don't need it, and even for the excerpt shown in lists it would not be truly necessary. There are pretty good reasons to avoid MathJax in titles anyway, and most sites that use it, but are not about math itself have rules or customs to avoid MathJax in titles.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin You're talking about a theoretical bit for a plugin that doesn't exist (do we change the database schema for every plugin we support?). You have to set it on create, edit, deletion, *and any related thing* that affects those of would cause a rebake. And all caches that involve any of those items. None of this is an issue on other sites because it's "every page has it" and bypasses the need to check. But that's costly in terms of performance.

Comment: @NickCraver Not sure I'm understanding (probably the main issue is I don't know what a "plugin" is). Right now the bulk of the answer seems to be concerned with MathJAX in titles, which is not what I'm asking for.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Question lists include part of the body, as does search. Regardless of if we enable it in titles or not (which would introduce an inconsistency with other MathJAX-enabled sites and add to user confusion), most of the problems still exist.

Comment: @NickCraver the previews in question lists break MathJax pretty often anyway, as they simply cut it off after the specified length. This is not something that happens rarely, but pretty often, you can usually find an example on the first few pages of the Math.SE questions list.  So I wouldn't really bother getting those to work, if that presents additional problems.

Comment: @MadScientist The alternative is they just look like garbled text, though. That's not good for users either.

Comment: @NickCraver that is already the reality right now for sites that use MathJax. I just checked the first 50 questions on Math.SE, four of them have broken MathJax in their previews.

Comment: Are "question lists" in the review queues? I checked front page, related, and hot network questions, which seem to be the hot paths, but can't spot any question bodies.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin You just click "Questions" in the nav to get there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: @MadScientist That's still very much a minority case, we're talking about making that the default behavior. That does more harm than good for the site's interface IMO. Even if it's a minority case *of the total question volume* (I don't think this point is in debate), *all* of them would be screwed up.

Comment: There are no perfect choices here. I think it is reasonable to make some assumptions for non-math sites here, and I strongly suspect that the math parts would usually not be visible in the preview because they're supporting the answers (or sometimes the question), but they're not the central theme. I could of course be wrong here.

Comment: @MadScientist I wouldn't make any assumptions, but either way you assume: bodies have the same issues in search. Some other areas I forgot: duplicate question search prompts, etc.

Comment: @NickCraver Ah, gotcha. Yeah, code, math etc. looks garbled in the previews; you can't expect to read Python or calculus in there. From what I understand you already do markdown stripping for the preview; you could just ellipsize the formulas if you think they look too ugly.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Then we're back to doing checks and allocations (paired assumptions) on the server for every listing everywhere. The user upside would have to be a huge win to justify that, and we're still not seeing that in your proposal.

Comment: @NickCraver You strip the markdown every time you render the questions list? The central assumption is that all the work I'm asking for (recognize whether mathjax is in the page, strip mathjax for preview, etc.) happens at the moment when the post is authored, not when you're rendering stuff millions of times a day.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin we don't strip the markdown, we pre-render the HTML of all posts because the runtime cost of doing Markdown baking would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Ok, so whenever it is you're pre-rendering the HTML, couldn't you also ellipsize the formulas (assuming you think this is less ugly than leaving them be)?

Comment: The formula elision work could be rolled into a "fix" for the behavior @MadScientist is describing btw, if you need an excuse :)

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin We *could* do a lot of things. At the cost of CPU, storage, and user performance. But all of those comes after the question of *is it worth it* from the **user** point of view. We haven't justified any of that in your proposal. None of the solutions are simple or cheap. Nor do they solve the problem for search. You're currently just increasing the scope of work with a bunch of "what if..." workarounds (and cost) without the basic justification first.

Comment: The basic justification is in the question you originally answered, and in the problem I described earlier in the question. Writing an answer on Stack Overflow that illustrates some mathematical concept rewards vague handwaving and punishes precise notation, especially over time. I am trying to discuss how it could be made cheap if not simple, but at the end of the day it's your site and you choose the features it is worth investing effort into.

Answer (score 3):

No, really...how often do questions on Stack Overflow use math compared to the number of questions that *don't*?

In my mind the effort isn't justified by the returns we'd get.  Stack Overflow is not overly math-heavy, and if the questions start slanting that way, there are other such as [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) which do allow for MathJax.

Comment: There's no way to find out, because the formulas are usually opaque images.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin:  It's actually incredibly rhetorical.  Out of the next 500 questions that come on Stack Overflow, maybe two or three will benefit from MathJax.  Given that MathJax has already been tested on Stack Overflow, and has been shown to cause a significant enough slowdown *without* any work to do, it seems to me that there's little benefit to justify enabling it.  I wouldn't mind it personally but I rather enjoy the fact that the site is very, very responsive.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin The onus is on *you* to show that adding the feature would be of a compelling benefit to a significant portion of posts, not on Makoto to show that it wouldn't be.   You're the one proposing the change; the burden is on *you* to show that it's going to actually be worthwhile.  That you can't is a major problem for your proposal.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, cool, but like I said, I can't find out because the formulas are usually images. There's no way to search for "posts that would have used mathjax if mathjax was a thing on stack overflow".

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin:  Then use inductive reasoning.  How many posts on Stack Overflow are code dumps?  Really, really bad homework problems? Users asking for configuration on their server?  Actual *on-topic* questions?  Then you ask how many of those on-topic questions actually *require* TeX of some kind, and that's the rough (and very unscientific but good gut-feel) estimate.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin That you can't write a compelling proposal for your feature request means that it shouldn't be implemented.  If/when you, or someone else, *is* able to provide a compelling argument that it would actually be of significant benefit, then it becomes worth considering.

Comment: @Servy I have a compelling proposal for the feature request; enable MathJAX only on pages that need it. I just don't have a way to collect the data Makoto is asking for.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin That's not evidence that this is actually of significant benefit.  It's an attempt to mitigate one of the downsides of the feature.

Comment: How often do questions on Stack Overflow use Haskell compared to the number of questions that don't? (not supporting using MathJax, just pointing out that this argument isn't all that great of an argument in and of itself, granted the fact that it would be a massive undertaking to implement would strengthen the argument).

Comment: @TinyGiant:  The site doesn't need to do anything to render Haskell outside of what it already does.  The site would have to do *more* to render MathJax, or to even carry it around.  Your counter point is a false analogy.

Comment: @Makoto Well, in the case of Haskell, before syntax highlighting was turned on something had to be done. It is the magnitude of the task that is the problem. If all that had to be done was turn on syntax highlighting it would be a non-issue, but _because_ it is such a massive undertaking, it is an issue.