# Mermaid diagrams markup extension

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor

As an architect, I meandered last few years from one to another "graph as a markup" solution. Until I found Mermaid.

Very often diagram is the best way to explain some question or give an non trivial answer.

I dare to say the Mermaid extension to the SO Markdown engine might be a very effective solution. MD would look like this:

````
    ```mermaid
      graph LR
         A --- B
         B-->C[fa:fa-ban forbidden]
         B-->D(fa:fa-spinner);
    ```
````

As an mature example, this kind of Markdown, is present and in use in [HUGO "Learn" theme](https://learn.netlify.com/en/shortcodes/mermaid/) behind a "HUGO" static CMS, documentation site.

Integration might be even described as "simple". [See here](https://mermaidjs.github.io/usage.html).

Comment: How many questions or answers would benefit from having this library?

Comment: If one thinks Markdown extension for visualisation is not benefititial here there is no much room for dicussion about "Mermaid" or "yUML" or any such thing

Comment: @ChefGladiator: Convince us that this is something SO ___needs___, and that it's worth the cost in rendering  / network usage. I'm sure the majority here would appreciate the added functionality, but is it feasible?

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR** This library is cool, but not a good fit for SO.

This is a cool library, but, as others have pointed out, it's not necessary or even helpful to nearly enough posts to justify its deployment here.

SO is a *huge* site, with millions of posts (*i.e.*, millions of pages), used by millions of people, covering tens of thousands of topics (*i.e.*, tags). The vast majority of these posts and tags would be unlikely to benefit significantly from the kind of charting available in this library, assuming users even knew about the functionality in question and bothered to learn how to use it. Yet the key issue when requesting a new feature on a site like this is whether we ***need*** it, not whether a few posts here and there would benefit from it.

The impact on site load and render times on the millions of posts on SO would be non-trivial, and so would the development and maintenance burden. But my guess is at most a few hundred posts per year would really derive any meaningful benefit from this functionality. As such, it's not a good idea to deploy it site-wide.

Comment: What library would be a "good fit" for SO?

Comment: To be a good fit, a library would need to offer significant, widespread benefits to users, sufficient to justify the development effort, maintenance effort, and performance impact on countless millions of question views. This library hasn’t cleared any of those hurdles; there’s no evidence that its impact would be significant at all, much less widespread.

Comment: Thank you. Can you name one library please?

Comment: jQuery, or whatever library is responsible for the text editor.

Comment: @ChefGladiator You can see which libraries have passed this test—that is, which ones are actually included on Q&A pages—as easily as we can. Just inspect the page using your browser's developer tools. There are not many, and they all serve some function that affects nearly every visitor, like jQuery (which, yes, is one).

Answer (score 8):

Integration may be simple, but what impact would this have on site load times?

For math, LaTeX markup via MathJax has been [requested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on) a couple of times, but the request [has been denied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/1835379) because of the library's negative impact on load times.

Who's to say this library won't have the same issues? Do the drawbacks outweigh the issues caused by not having the library?

I'm not convinced.

If you need a diagram in a question or answer, it's pretty trivial to include a screenshot of a diagram.

Comment: LaTex is not diagrams. Diagram is much wider in scope than math equations rendering. If one thinks Markdown extension for visualisation is not benefititial here there is no much room for dicussion about "Mermaid" or "yUML" or any such thing., btw, yUML oen can use right now on SO. It will depend on yuml,me delivering the image but it works ok.

Comment: @ChefGladiator: The LaTeX example was just an example of the costs vs benefits consideration of adding external rendering libraries to SO's markdown parser. I'm not arguing that it wouldn't be nice to have, I'm just not convinced if the added page load (network & rendering) for ___every___ visitor on SO outweighs the added functionality.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying why you have mentoned LaTeX.

Comment: I don't see any reason why lazy loading would not work ...

Comment: @JonasWilms: [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), and a rather jarring one in the case of diagrams like that. Markdown is parsed server-size and the resulting HTML is passed to the client.

Comment: You have a point there. Sth like `<div style="display:none">graph LR ...</div>` would work though. But IMO the main point here is that only a small number of people would benefit from it (they can still use images, so its not really an issue), and there are more important issues the SO dev team should focus on (review, for example)

Comment: @JonasWilms: that could work, provided the library is only loaded when needed... But that would add a extra bit of complexity, if something is edited adding the need for the library.

Comment: Dear All, let me repeat here to: The issue was using Opera desktop browser. Chrome worketh just fine. Curiously Opera Touch (mobile devices browser) also works fine. The only issue is yuml.me possibly dissapearing sometimes in the future.