# Integrate LaTeX in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I would like to have Latex interpreter support in our team's site, as in math.stackexchange for example. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, what is implemented on [Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed) is [Mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/), which does not provide all the functionality of Latex, but gives most features relevant for math. I would definitely like to see this become available for Teams.

Comment: Iirc, to add that on Teams, they'd have to add it to SO, which [isn't going to happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on)

Comment: @Cerbrus, thanks for letting me know. Clearly the argument against ("load time") can be irrelevant for Teams. Preferably on Teams this should be admin decision.

Comment: The problem is that teams isn't an independent product, as far as I know.

Comment: @Cerbrus, indeed. At first I wanted to get rid of all the SO tags. Couldn't do it, but could live with that. and now this. Teams can be used much more generally (i.e., not necessarily related to code development)  than the SE team seem to realize. if we have other sites in SE which are not SO, why Teams has to be restricted to SO.

Comment: It is _the same product_, teams is an extension built _onto_ SO, as far as I’m aware. Just like you can’t use electric trains on a rail net that does’n have the required infrastructure, you can’t uze LaTex in teams if SO doesnMt have that infrastructure.

Comment: Does anyone know of a good extension that does this?